# Can't login using cf command

Tags: cloud-foundry

After setting the target to api.cloudfoundry.com I can't login doing "cf login".

I'm sure about my credentials because I can login into login.cloudfoundry.com.

Could be something to do with the new version?

I've seen that some times you asked for `cf login -t output` so, here is mine:
 changing the password for `*****`

```
Authenticating.  --->
request: post https://uaa.cloudfoundry.com/oauth/token
headers: content-typeapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8acceptapplication/json;charset=utf-8authorizationBasic Y2Y6
body: grant_type=password&username=bertyno%40yahoo.es&password=******
...<---
response: 401
headers: content-typeapplication/json;charset=utf-8servernginxkeep-alivetimeout=20dateMon, 13 May 2013 12:19:13 GMTtransfer-encodingchunkedwww-authenticateBasic realm="UAA/client", error="unauthorized", error_description="No client with requested id: cf"cache-controlno-storeconnectionclose
body: {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"No client with requested id: cf"}
--->
request: post https://uaa.cloudfoundry.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuaa.cloudfoundry.com%2Fredirect%2Fcf&client_id=cf&response_type=token&state=2b7fbfd964323e8c639da0157c00435b
headers: content-typeapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8acceptapplication/json;charset=utf-8
body: username=bertyno%40yahoo.es&password=******&source=credentials
...<---
response: 401
headers: pragmano-cache, no-cachecontent-languageen-UScontent-typeapplication/json;charset=UTF-8servernginxkeep-alivetimeout=20dateMon, 13 May 2013 12:19:14 GMTtransfer-encodingchunkedcache-controlno-cache, no-store, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0expiresThu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMTconnectionclose
body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}
... FAILED
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use --sso to do the successful login. The command will look like

`cf login <optional params> --sso`

So it'll ask you to enter some passcode which you can retrieve from the web login.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry v2 is behind the endpoint api.run.pivotal.io.

If you had a user registered on Cloud Foundry v1, its credentials have been copied over to run.pivotal.io.

Quick-Start:

```
gem install cf
cf target api.run.pivotal.io
cf login
```

Full doc: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/dotcom/getting-started.html

Migration: http://www.cloudfoundry.com/faq#migrating

Comment: Note that at the moment I did get to login. However I could not do anything more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056241/unable-to-select-a-space-or-join-an-organization-on-run-pivotal-io

Answer (score -1):

Cloudfoundry.com sent me a e-mail about cloudfoundry v2 launch (5th june):

> CloudFoundry.com V2 will be available around June 10th!!!

You can check the current API supported by cloudfoundry.com in http://api.cloudfoundry.com/info

Your apps in cloudfoundry v1 will not be migrate automatically to cloudfoundry v2:

> You will need to migrate your apps and data from the V1 service prior
>   to deletion on June 30th

**cf** is CLI to access to cloudfoundry v2 and **vmc** is CLI for cloudfoundry v1. I suppose that your current user in cloudfoundry v1 (the one you use in *vmc login*) must be migrated to v2 also (new *cf login* command).