# Unable to select a space or join an organization on run.pivotal.io

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am attempting to use Cloud Foundry v2 on run.pivotal.io

I am following the documentation: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/dotcom/getting-started.html; using the credentials of my user registered on Cloud Foundry v1 (cloudfoundry.com).

```
gem install cf
cf --version
cf 2.1.0
cf login
...
Authenticating... OK
CFoundry::NotAuthorized: 10003: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
... not authorised log:
REQUEST: GET https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/organizations?inline-relations-depth=0
```

At this point the documentation states I should get an interactive prompt to select a space.

I have attempted to list/create spaces and organisation. cf always returns a CFoundry::NotAuthorized.

Let me know what I am missing!
Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried my _gmail.com_ account, _sutoiku.com_ and _stoic.cc_ accounts and they are facing this issue. Somehow my _comware.com.au_ account did work.

Answer (score 2):

What I needed to do first was to login on the web console at
http://console.run.pivotal.io
I then prompted to create an organisation and all is good now.

My question got answered on the support forums of pivotal here:
https://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/24126377-Unable-to-join-an-organisation-on-run-pivotal-io?page=1#post_23711398